# SQL - Select Key by ID [same table]

Tags: mysql, sql

Hey Community i very new with sql and i have a question... i have a mysql database and i want to get the LICENSE (look at the table) by ID.
That means when i have `48614` from the table the output should be `JJAISDNM`

```
+----------+-------------+
| ID       | LICENSE     |
+----------+-------------+
| 48614    | JJAISDNM    |
| 3448234  | KDFIFEWSDF  |
+----------+-------------+
```

I tried this... but i cant go further

```
SELECT table FROM keys WHERE ...
```

Comment: Hint:  `WHERE id = 48614`.

Comment: sql query is `SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID=48614`

Comment: Is `keys` really the table's name? Are you in the question here? It'd be nice to get some feedback.

Answer (score 1):

If the name of the table is 'keys', then this should work 
`SELECT LICENSE FROM keys WHERE ID = 48614`

Answer (score -1):

We consider your table's name is keys:

```
SELECT LICENSE FROM `keys` WHERE ID=48614
```